# "Redis 'server' not specified." in Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis code

Tags: configuration, server-setup, redis

I have followed all the tutorials on github, did everything exactly as explained:
1. installed Redis
2. modmanned Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis
3. Tried with and without template.php in app\code\local\Mage\Core\Block
4. Obviously edited our local.xml and it has server specs:

```
    <host>127.0.0.1</host> <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
    <port>6379</port>
```

One thing remains no matter what we tried, we did verify with our host. Google gives only 4 unrelated results, so please... ;-)

We keep getting an error report containing this:
a:4:{i:0;s:29:"Redis 'server' not specified.";i:1;s:1585:"#0 /magento/domains/domain.com/public_html/.modman/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php(122): Zend_Cache::throwException('Redis 'server' ...')

I'm lost. Who has an idea what to try next?

Edit: 
Magento version 1.9.2
Did a PING on the server to redit and that came back with PONG as well.

Answer (score 2):

FINALLY figured it out although it was pretty obvious.

My lines, which I copied from the many many sample sites, are

```
<host>127.0.0.1</host>
```

If you look at it, it is self explanatory, since it says it is missing a SERVER, so I looked at the (yup, should have immediately) local.xml.additional from Magento and noticed it should say server, and not host, like this:

```
<server>127.0.0.1</server>
```

Thanks for looking, hope it helps some others.